# Speeding up jenkinsapi

Tags: jenkins

Our CI system uses the python module jenkinsapi to launch test jobs on Jenkins. But it's slow - the time taken to run a single job varies between 10 - 30 seconds. That really bogs the system down.

Our production Jenkins is tied into our corporate LDAP. Hence jenkinsapi requires a username/password. Without a doubt this contributes to the problem. I suspect that each time it runs a job it needs to perform a login on Jenkins. The issue is vastly reduced when I run the setup against my local unsecured instance of Jenkins.

Is there any way to workaround these limitation? Can I speed up the execution of jenkinsapi? Or is there an alternative approach that will work better with a secure Jenkins?

Comment: Worked around this by having a public job launch the test jobs. i.e. Lost security. In another scenario we moved to the groovy api which dropped job execution time from 15 minutes to 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If the LDAP authentication is really the bottleneck, you may be able to get around it by using the [user's API token](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) instead of the password on API login. It should be as simple as replacing the password with the API token (available on the user's configuration page in Jenkins) in your scripts.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion - but we recently did this for other reasons and it had little effect on performance. Perhaps it's not as related to the LDAP authentication as I assumed. Might be more to do with Jenkins itself?

Comment: @Shane Too bad. The LDAP configuration has a cache that you can turn on, but it's not clear whether LDAP is involved (it might be depending on whether you authorize by group). There might be a Jenkins issue or there might be improvements you can make in your scripts, but it's hard to guess without more details. I recommend checking the Jenkins logs and tracing the communication with Wireshark to see whether you can figure out where the delay is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the parameter:  lazy=True

```
server = Jenkins(
    JENKINS_HOST,
    username=JENKINS_USER,
    password=JENKINS_TOKEN,
    lazy=True,
)
```